# Bootstrap плавающий div с прокруткой

Tags: css, css3, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы на экране было две колонки - левая и правая. В каждой колонке по таблице. При выборе строки в левой таблице загружается таблица справа. И было бы удобно, если бы правая таблица "плавала" с возможностью её прокрутки, если не помещается на экран.

Ниже прикреплён вроде бы рабочий пример, но таблица справа сжимается до минимальной ширины, а нужно, чтобы была по размеру колонки. Bootstrap 4.1

Как быть?

```css
#table_div {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row my-3">
    <div class="col-6">
      <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">r1</th>
            <th scope="col">r2</th>
            <th scope="col">r3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div>
        <div id="table_div">
          <table class="table table-sm table-hover" id="my_table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">r1</th>
                <th scope="col">r2</th>
                <th scope="col">r3</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Изменил немного разметку второй колонки - будьте внимательны

```css
#parentCol{
  padding:0
}
#table_div {  
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row my-3">
    <div class="col-6">
      <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">r1</th>
            <th scope="col">r2</th>
            <th scope="col">r3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" id="parentCol">
      <div class="col-6" id="table_div">
        <table class="table table-sm table-hover" id="my_table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">r1</th>
              <th scope="col">r2</th>
              <th scope="col">r3</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```